# How to avoid duplication in db when import .xls file codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

xls file and saving data into db everything is correct but i want to stop duplication when i import file it escape duplication and insert other data.

data insertion is correct but how to stop duplication.

here is my controller code

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numCols']; $i++) 
{
    if($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$HeadingRow][$i]=='user')
        $columnsArr['virtual_card_name'] = $i;
    if($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$HeadingRow][$i]=='department')
        $columnsArr['department'] = $i;


    for ($i = $dataStartRow; $i<=$data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) 
    {

        $colsData['virtual_card_name'] = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$columnsArr['virtual_card_name']]; 
        $colsData['department'] = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$columnsArr['department']]; 

        $returnMsg = $this->Admin_fund_transfer_model->insertCardsData($colsData);  

        $num++;
    }
```

Model

```
function insertCardsData($data)
{
    $this->db->insert("cards", $data);
    return  $this->db->insert_id();         
}
```

Comment: if some one add same department name or card name it should show duplication error..

Answer (score 0):

You could add a unique key to your database so that it doesn't allow duplicates to be added. You do, of course, have to be clear as to what you mean by duplicate.